# passing reference var and GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, pass-by-value

If we pass a reference variable to method and modify the object's state, the modifications are permanent (Please correct me if I am wrong). Consider the code:

```
 class CardBoard {
    Short story = 200;
    CardBoard go(CardBoard cb) {                        //....(1)
    cb = null;
    return cb;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    CardBoard c1 = new CardBoard();
    CardBoard c2 = new CardBoard();
    CardBoard c3 = c1.go(c2);       //pass c2 into a method ....(2)
    c1 = null;
    // do Stuff
    } }
```

When in the above code, we say cb=null and return cb, shouldn't c2 (and also c3) now have null reference? (PS: The original question asks for the objects that are eligible for gc after "//do stuff". The answer is given to be 2, but I am having problem in understanding it.)

Comment: No, because the reference is passed by value. There are *lots* of questions on Stack Overflow (and other pages on the net) which go into this in a lot of detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because `cb=null` only replace the referencing target of 'cb' from the original instance to `null`, therefore `c2` won't be affected.

When you just pass `c2` into the function, the situation would be something like this:

```
  cb       c2 
  |         | 
------------------
|      object    |
------------------
```

once `cb` is set to `null`, it becomes

```
null--cb       c2 
               | 
  -------------------
  |      object     |
  -------------------
```

and you return cb and assign to c3, it essentially does `c3 = null`.

However, on the other hand, if you change the internal state of that object, then certainly the state of the object referred by all the references will be changed..

Answer (score 0):

Java is strictly *pass by value*.

```
CardBoard go(CardBoard cb) { // here cb has a *copy* of address c2 points to
  cb = null; // when you modify cb, c2 still points to the original location
  return cb; // returning null now
}

CardBoard c3 = c1.go(c2); // c3 becomes null because of explicit assignment
c1 = null; // same as c3
```

Much of your confusion comes from observing this

> If we pass a reference variable to method and modify the object's state, the modifications are permanent.

which appears as *pass by reference* but in Java works as *pass by value (of the reference)*.

The modifications persist because the *copy* (of the address) still points to the original object. So, all the methods fired (using the *copy* reference) still fire on the original object.

But, if you were to destroy this copied reference (by setting it to *null*) it won't affect the original object or any other references pointing to it.

Comment: cb is a pointer to the same object, not a copy

Comment: @Tala Please refresh the answer. I had already reworded it.

Comment: ok, revoked the vote down